# perl Find::File and smart matching producing corrupted double-linked list

Tags: perl, find

I am trying to write a program that reads all files recursively from some top point into an array and subsequently read lines of filenames from a separate file, trying to print if those filenames are present in the earlier array.

my program churns through the 43K files in the directory structure and subsequently gets through about 300 of the 400 lines in the file before providing me with a spectactular "*** glibc detected**  perl: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000000a30740 **"

Which I have no knowledge about at all..  Could this be an 'out of memory' type bug?  I can't imagine it is not since the host has 24G of memory.

Do you have any idea where I'm going wrong?  I was trying to save time and effort by reading the entire list of files from the subdirectory into an array one time and subsequently matching against it using the shorter list of files from the filename given as ARGV[0].

Here is my code:

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
  use warnings;
  use strict;
  use diagnostics;

  use File::Find;
  use 5.010001;

  ## debug subroutine
  my $is_debug = $ENV{DEBUG} // 0;
  sub debug { print "DEBUG: $_[0]\n" if $is_debug };

  ## exit unless properly called with ARGV
  die "Please provide a valid filename: $!" unless $ARGV[0] && (-e $ARGV[0]);

  my @pic_files;
  my $pic_directory="/files/multimedia/pictures";

  find( sub {
     push @pic_files, $File::Find::name
        if -f && ! -d ;
     }, $pic_directory);

  open LIST, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "Could not open $ARGV[0]: $!";

  while(<LIST>) {
     chomp;
     debug "\$_ is ->$_<-";

     if ( @pic_files ~~ /.*$_/i ) {
        print "found: $_\n";
     } else {
        print "missing: $_\n";
     }
  }
  close LIST or die "Could not close $ARGV[0]: $!";
```

And here is a sample of the file:

```
DSC02338.JPG  
DSC02339.JPG  
DSC02340.JPG  
DSC02341.JPG  
DSC02342.JPG  
DSC02343.JPG  
DSC02344.JPG  
DSC02345.JPG  
DSC02346.JPG  
DSC02347.JPG
```

And the obligitory error:

```
missing: DSC02654.JPG   
DEBUG:  is ->DSC02655.JPG<-   
missing: DSC02655.JPG   
DEBUG:  is ->DSC02656.JPG<-   
missing: DSC02656.JPG   
*** glibc detected *** perl: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000000a30740 ***   
======= Backtrace: =========   
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x71bd6)[0x7fb6d15dbbd6]   
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x7553f)[0x7fb6d15df53f]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first thing people will ask is which version of perl on what platform etc. Add the long version output to your post.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very inefficient algorithm.  You are running 21,500 * n regexes, where n is the number of files in LIST.  My guess is, this is opening you up to some kind of underlying memory issue or bug.

Here is an alternative approach that would be much more efficient without many changes.  First, read the files into a hash rather than an array (I added `lc` to make everything lowercase, since you want case-insensitive matching):

```
  my %pic_files;

  find( sub {
     $pic_files{lc $File::Find::name}++
        if -f && ! -d ;
     }, $pic_directory);
```

*Edit:* Second, rather than using a regex to search every single file in the directory, use a regex on the input line to intelligently find potential matches.

```
my $path_portion = lc $_;
my $found = 0;
do {
     if (exists $pic_files{$path_portion} or exists $pic_files{'/' . $path_portion} )
     {
         $found = 1;
     }
} while (!found and $path_portion =~ /\/(.*)$/ and $path_portion = $1);

if ($found) { print "found: $_"; }
else { print "not found: $_\n"; }
```

This checks the path in the input file, then lops off the first directory in the path each time it does not match and checks again.  It should be much faster, and hopefully this strange bug will go away (though it would be nice to figure out what was happening; if it is a bug in Perl, your version becomes very important, since smart match is a new feature that has had a lot of recent changes and bug fixes).

Comment: wow.. removing smart match and focusing on putting the filenames into a hash DRAMATICALLY sped up the process.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't seen an error like this before, I suspect it is being caused by generating a 43,000-element list of files and using it in a smart match. Are you using a 64-bit perl?

You also make things more difficult by storing the full path to each file when all you need to match is the base file name.

This really isn't the sort of thing smart match is good for, and I suggest that you should create a hash of the file names in the input file and mark them off one by one as `find` comes across them

This program shows the idea. I don't have a perl installation at hand so I can't test it but it looks OK

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my $listfile = shift;
die "Please provide a valid filename" unless $listfile;
open my $list, '<', $listfile or die "Unable to open '$listfile': $!";

my %list;
while (<$list>) {
  chomp;
  $list{$_} = 0;
}
close $list;

my $pic_directory = '/files/multimedia/pictures';

find( sub {
  if (-f and exists $list{$_}) {
    print "found: $_\n";
    $list{$_}++;
  }
}, $pic_directory);

for my $file (keys %list) {
  print "missing: $_\n" unless $list{$file};
}
```

Comment: wow.. moving away from smart matching to simply putting the basenames into a hash and checking against them DRAMATICALLY sped up the process.

Thanks for the advice although I still would like to understand smart matching a bit more.

The program even blows away the equivalent bash shell that used find for the same comparison.